# Error when setting 4000000 UART Baud rate at RPI 4

Tags: pi-4, uart

I'm trying to run communication with my hardware using RPi built-in UART ports. I need to use 3 UART ports at 4M baud rate.
I added to /boot/config.txt following lines at the end:

```
dtoverlay=uart5
dtoverlay=uart2
```

And switched off serial console from raspi-config

When I try to configure /dev/ttyAMA1 or /dev/ttyAMA2 I get following error:

```
Exception: Command 'stty -F /dev/ttyAMA1 4000000' returned non-zero exit status 1.
stty: /dev/ttyAMA1: unable to perform all requested operations
```

Maximum what is possible to set is 2000000. I checked that echo works fine, but I didn't verify if it's really 2M with oscilloscope.

I found some answers related to UART clock speed but they seems to be obsolete - they are all about RPI2 or RPI3 and only UART0.

Question: How to set baud rate to 4000000 for any 3 ports of RPi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change [`init_uart_clock`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md) to at least 64000000 in order to get 4Mbps baudrate.

And I wouldn't be surprised if setting the baudrate to 2Mbps without any changes actually results in 1.5Mbps effective baudrate: baudrates typically are integer divisions of the maximum, which is 3Mbps by default.

It is also possible that the change will result in standard baudrates such as 115200 becoming unstable: 4Mbps/35 is 114286, which about 0.8% error from 115200. The critical error value is about 1-2% for most UART implementations. For comparison, 3Mbps/26 yields 115385, which is is only 0.16% error.

Comment: Thanks! It works, however - this works only for the PL011 UART - not miniUart, which is available at the default. I had to disable BT module by adding dtoverlay=disable-bt additionally. More info here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

Comment: Yeah, the mini-uart clock is tied to the GPU clock, so it's more difficult to use it.